# Display image when method occurs

Tags: python, class, oop, processing

I changed my code and tested numerous times to no avail. To put it into context, I am trying to display a health bar in a Python game (developed on Processing) and I have five images of depleting health. The images load perfectly well. I would like to know if it is possible to have the following happen, where `onCollision()` is when two players collide:

```
def healthbar(self):
        if self.onCollision():
            image(self.health,30,500,200,25,0,25,200,50)
```

I also tried to have boolean logic in `onCollision()` such that when it is `True`, the following happens:

```
def healthbar(self):
        if self.hitLogic==True:
            image(self.health,30,500,200,25,0,25,200,50)
```

Of course I defined `self.hitLogic=False` in the initializer of the class.

**My question is if it is possible to load an image in Python if a boolean is true or a method occurs.**

Side-note: I am not using pygame.

Edit: the images load fine independently, but do not load when I call `if self.onCollision()` or `if self.hitLogic==True`. That is the problem I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to load an [image()](http://py.processing.org/reference/image.html) in [Processing.py](http://py.processing.org/reference/) in any function that is called by `draw()`. The image will appear along with all other drawing commands when the `draw()` loop finishes its cycle.

Your problem is not a structural limitation of Python -- and keep in mind that **Processing.py uses Jython**, so your Python code becomes Java before it runs!

You can debug this kind of problem with:

```
if(True);
  image(self.health  ...  )
```

If it does work, your variable isn't setting or your method isn't returning True at call-time, and you need to debug the code that you haven't shared. For further help on this please update your question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Arguments 6-9 'cut' the image, such that `0,25` is x1,y1 and `200,50` is x2,y2. In one image, I have 5 health bars placed next to one another so I do not need to create 5 different images of depleting health bars. As I said, the images load fine independently, but do not load when I call `if self.onCollision()` or `if self.hitLogic==True`. That is the problem I have.

Comment: As I said, this is possible. Without seeing your code, there is no way to find your bug. However, try writing `if(True); image(self.health ...)`. What happens? If it doesn't work, your image call isn't working. If it does work, your variable isn't set or your method isn't returning True at call-time, and you need to debug the code that you haven't shared -- it has nothing to do with the structure of Python or Processing as a language.

Comment: `if(True)` did work for the different 'cuts' of images. Thanks for your reassuring comment - I really thought it was an issue with the structure of Python. I will now try to debug further and hopefully it works.

Comment: Glad to hear it -- let me know if I can provide any other feedback about the timing of the draw loop calls etc. Keep in mind that **Processing.py uses jython** -- so really, the python code becomes Java before it runs!

Comment: Thank you!! Interesting, never knew that!

Comment: It eventually worked perfectly for me. I just had the logic behind how the images are supposed to be displayed wrong, but managed to fix it as soon as I understood.